# ¿Como llamar a un evento de java desde Node JS?

Tags: java, nodejs

Tengo una aplicacion en java que se conecta a un biométrico. La idea es ejecutar sus funciones desde una app en node pasando por Java. ¿Es posible llamar a dicha función de Java desde node? Por ejemplo:

```
public static void llamando() {
    System.out.println("Hola Mundo");
}
```

Al pulsar un botón desde Node:

```
 $('call_java_function').click(function(){
     llamando();
 });
```

Nota: es java desktop.

Comment: Hola, que estás tramando? Si es una webapp exponé un servicio. De otra manera podés compilar el jar y ejecutar desde la terminal el metodo main de la clase que quieras con algo así "java -cp test.jar path.to.Class". Quizá haya manera pero no creo que sea nada sencillo, y además sería poco útil. Como te dije, expone un servicio si es una webapp y sino, invocá tu funcionalidad java con java -jar o java -cp

Comment: tengo una aplicacion en java que se conecta a un biométrico, la idea es ejecutar sus funciones desde una app en node pasando por java

Comment: ¿Tu aplicación Java está empaquetada en un jar que se encuentra en el mismo server donde instalaste Node? ¿Estarán en servidores por separado?

Comment: las dos app estarán en la misma PC

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es que expongas una funcionalidad que se llame por consola.

Cuando se ejecuta el metodo main de una clase, recibe un array de String que contiene los parametros que le podés pasar por consola

```
java -jar app.jar param1 param2 param3
```

y en el main esto estaría asi

```
public static void main(String[] params) {
    //params tendría ["param1", "param2", "param3"]
}
```

Sabiendo esto podrías llamar acá a tu método `llamando()` partiendo desde main y exponer los resultados en un archivo de texto quizá para que lo consuma tu app en node.